# “Я знаю (то), что ты обманула меня.”

Tags: грамматика

Насколько я понимаю, классические правила русского языка запрещают опускать слово ***то*** в предложениях вроде

> Я знаю ***то***, что ты обманула меня.

Правда ли, что опускать здесь ***то*** стало современной литературной нормой? Я всегда так делал, и начал сомневаться только после знакомства с правилами.

Comment: could you please post a reference to the "classical rules" you're mentioning? Thanks!

Comment: "То" в данном случае - не частица, а часть составного союза.

Comment: Оба варианта вполне нормальные. Тут дело не в грамматике, а, скорее уж, в стилистике.

Comment: @Quassnoi, я не видел ничего конкретного, но так понимаю, что после *знаю* должно идти существительное или местоимение, здесь -- *то*, но не дополнительная часть предложения.

Comment: @se0808: I'm not aware of any guidebook which would have required it. As Matt above mentioned, both variants are acceptable.

Comment: @se0808 Может идти и [целое предложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае правильно будет как раз без "то", потому что второстепенное предложение отвечает на вопрос главного:

> - Я знаю что?
>
> - Что ты обманула меня.

"То" необходимо в другом случае, например: "Я знаю то, чего не должен знать".

> - Я знаю что?
>
> - **То**, чего не должен знать.

Если написать "Я знаю то, чего не должен знать", без "то", смысл получится совсем другой:

> - Я знаю что?
>
> - Чего (я) не должен знать.

В первом случае говорящий владеет какой-то излишней информацией ("Я владею информацией, которой, по идее, владеть не должен"). А во втором - знает список вещей, которых он не должен знать ("Я знаю, какой информацией я не должен владеть"). Допустим, я каким-то образом узнала новую секретную технологию создания сверхмощного оружия, которая является государственной тайной и точно не должна быть известна мне, простому обывателю. В этом случае я могу сказать: "Я знаю **то**, чего не должна знать". А может быть совсем другая ситуация: я не знаю самой технологии, но зато точно знаю, что она засекречена, и если я ее каким-то образом узнаю, у меня будут неприятности. А кроме этого, есть и другие вещи, которых я также не должна знать, по тем или иным причинам. Например, я не должна знать пин-код от чужой банковской карты, не должна знать медицинский диагноз моего знакомого (если он не хочет его раскрывать), не должна знать подробностей чужой личной жизни, и т.д. Все знания такого рода я могу выразить предложением "Я знаю, чего не должна знать." (при этом не важно, владею ли я на самом деле этими излишними знаниями, или нет).

Именно Ваше предложение будет понятно и сохранит смысл и с "то", хоть и будет звучать несколько неестественно. Но во многих случаях "то" существенно меняет смысл.

---

**Еще несколько примеров, где "то" существенно влияет на смысл предложения:**

**1)** Представьте, что вы заходите на кухню и видите на столе миску с яблоками. Вы можете сказать:

> Я вижу, где лежат яблоки.

А теперь представьте, что миска с яблоками закрыта крышкой. Самих яблок вы не видите (хоть и знаете, где они), только миску. Поэтому предыдущее предложение вы сказать не можете. Зато можете сказать: "Я вижу **миску**, где лежат яблоки." Или, если вы забыли слово "миска", либо яблоки лежат в какой-то посуде, названия которой вы не знаете, вы можете сказать:

> Я вижу **то**, где лежат яблоки.

В данном случае все внимание сконцентрировано на посуде, а видите вы яблоки или нет - не важно.

---

**2)** Художник может сказать:

> Я рисую, где живу.

Это значит, что он работает (рисует) у себя дома. Содержание его картин в данном случае не имеет значения. Значение такое же, как если бы он сказал: "Я рисую там же, где живу". Но также он может сказать:

> Я рисую **то**, где живу.

Здесь смысл совсем другой - художник рисует интерьер своего дома, и все равно, где он сам при этом находится.

---

**3)** Девушка может сказать:

> Я знаю **того**, за кого хочу выйти замуж.

Это то же самое, что "Я знакома с тем человеком, за которого хочу выйти замуж". Но есть и другой вариант, она может сказать:

> Я знаю, за кого хочу выйти замуж.

В этом случае она просто знает, чего хочет от будущего мужа, но неизвестно, знакома ли она на данный момент с подходящим человеком, и существует ли он вообще.

Comment: почему смысл другой? прочитал объяснение, но не очень понимаю - я бы и так, и так сказал

Comment: Аналогично, не вижу разницы.

Comment: @JustinMcGuire, я добавила более подробное объяснение и еще несколько примеров. Надеюсь, теперь будет понятнее.

Comment: @Vilmar, может быть, тот пример не совсем удачный. Я добавила еще несколько, теперь видите?

Comment: @Lara Да, теперь понятнее, что вы имели ввиду, хотя во втором примере третьего пункта смысл не обязательно такой, как вы описали ("Я знаю, за кого хочу выйти замуж. За Васю!"), а вторые примеры других пунктов немного режут слух.

Comment: @Vilmar, да, примеры несколько искусственые. Но они нужны только для того, чтобы показать, в чем смысл слова "то" в предложениях данного вида. Кстати, во всех этих примерах "то" является указательным местоимением. А какой частью речи оно является в примере автора вопроса, и какую смысловую нагрузку несет?

Comment: А с Васей - ну да, может быть и такое значение, суть от этого не меняется. В предложении с "того" главным является факт знакомства с нужным человеком, а без - факт знания, за кого  она хочет замуж (будь то конкретный человек или какие-то абстрактные представления).

Comment: @Lara В примере автора это все то же указательное местоимение, выполняющее функцию соотносительного (союзного) слова

Answer (score 5):

Это предложение грамматически верно как с *"то"*, так и без него. Стилистически вне контекста без *"то"* оно звучит лучше. *"То"* уместно, если есть цель сделать акцент на второй части предложения, привлечь внимание слушателя к тому, что сейчас последует.

> Я не знаю, какими благими намерениями ты руководствовалась. Я знаю то,
> что ты обманула меня. Вот что для меня имеет значение.
>
> Я понял то, что те, кто меня любят по-настоящему, не что-то
> выдуманное, а меня, они любят меня не потому, что я хороший, а потому,
> что они прекрасны. (Е. Гришковец)

Такое применение можно сравнить с использованием глагола *"to do"* в предложении *"I do know that you lied to me."*

Необходимым *"то"* становится в сложноподчиненных предложениях, в которых придаточная часть выносится в начало.

> То, что вы накануне были у дома убитого, видели горничная и дворник.